# Why is this code causing an 'Invalid Floating Point Operation' error?

Tags: delphi

When executing the below code, it should calculate the distance to the horizon using the current height, but it is able to calculate only up to 63 meters high, then an 'Invalid Floating Point Operation' from 64 meters onwards.

Why is this error occurring?

```
unit Unit_ch4_2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r:real;
begin
  r := SQRT(SQR(6350000 + StrToint(Edit1.Text)) - SQR(6350000));
  Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(r / 1000);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @remy lebeau
I'm not good at English
Thank you for correcting both questions when I am uploading it on the translation site

Have a good day, teacher

Comment: Surely because interpretation of 6350000. 
Change this constant to 6350000.0 and see what occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types used in your code are too small to hold bigger intermediate values respectively Delphi assumes wrong about what intermediate data types to use here by your calls to `SQR` and `StrToInt`!

When you explicitly tell the compiler to use a bigger data type like `Int64` by defining a constant of that type and by using `StrToInt64` the code now runs without errors with entered values up to 99 999 999 999!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  v: int64 = 6350000;
var
  r: real;
  a: int64;
begin
  Edit2.Clear;
  a := SQR(v + StrToInt64(Edit1.Text)); // this line can give a negative result when the parameter passed to SQR is too big
  r := SQRT(a - SQR(v)); // negative parameter of SQRT causes an error!
  Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(r / 1000);
end;
```

In the code above I used an extra line for storing an intermedia value in an extra local variable, to show which part of the calculation exactly caused the error. If the parameter of `SQR` is too big (even when `Int64` is used), the result in `a` is a negative number. This then leads to an error when calling `SQRT`!

Below is a code version in the same short format as you used:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  v: int64 = 6350000;
var
  r: real;
begin
  Edit2.Clear;
  r := SQRT(SQR(v + StrToInt64(Edit1.Text)) - SQR(v));
  Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(r / 1000);
end;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your quick answer.
What I was curious about was solved right away.

If you want to express a bigger number,
When coding Int64 and StrToInt64, I will refer to the teacher's answer so that there is no error like this error

Have a nice day!

Comment: FYI, in the original code, the `Integer` version of `SQR()` was being used. The highest number it can safely square without overflowing the result is 46340, which is WAY below 6350000. Hence why you need to use the `Int64` or `Extended` version instead.

Comment: @상프로TV I think in your case I would replace integer arithmetic with floats completely. Just use `6350000.0` (note the trailing `.0`).

Comment: I added [.0] to 6350000 from the original code, and it works like this
I think both are good ways
Thank you for your good answer.

Comment: @상프로TV You're dealing with distances - these should probably be floating point values anyway.

Comment: I don't like this answer. Like the other commentators, since you are going to do the sqrt with floating point you are better moving to floating point immediately.